# Ruby File Upload Size

Tags: ruby, file, file-upload

I'm trying to test the size of an upload to validate its size.  Outside of the upload algos, simply looking at the temp file is where I'm having the issue.  I have a test file on my desktop named `test1.png`, which is 115 KB.

```
a = '/users/rich/desktop/test1.png'
s = File.open(a, 'wb')
r = File.size(a)
p r                         => 0
p s.size                    => 0
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but both resolve to 0.  Not true.

How can I get the size of a file?

Comment: Ya I wasn't far off.  The file was overwritten empty due to my "w" as File.open parameters.  So it was buggy.

Comment: You could also shell out to the system, using backticks. For example, `n = 'wc -c temp'.to_i #=> 65'`, where  `'wc -c temp' #=> "65 temp\n"` (read my single quotes as backticks). See [this article](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2012/10/18/backtick-system-exec-in-ruby.html) for details. My file `"temp"` contains, "We like pancakes for breakfast, but we know others like waffles."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `'w'` flag, since it **truncates existing file to zero length**, so, since you open the file *before* getting its size, you get `0`.

To get the size you could just use the path of the file **without using `File.open`**:

```
a = '/users/rich/desktop/test1.png'
File.size(a)
```

Or, if you need to create the `File` object, just use the `'r'` flag:

```
a = '/users/rich/desktop/test1.png'
s = File.open(a, 'r')
```

Now you can either use `File.size(a)` or `s.size` to get the size of the file.

Comment: OK, that first test1.png file was actually overwritten, so it was a false negative perhaps.  But thank you.